# Recursive nesting in equation building

Tags: python, recursion, nested

I want to code an "application" that will plot the nth reagent's concentration in time function of a chain reaction: A->B->C->D->...

The thing is, c_n(t) contains 2^n - 1 exponential functions - which are nested based on a pattern I've found:

```
c_1(t) = c_0_1 * exp(-k_1 * t)

c_2(t) = c_0_2 * exp(-k_2 * t) + c_0_1 * k_1 * {[exp(-k_1 * t) - exp(-k_2 * t)]/[k_2 - k_1]}

c_3(t) = c_0_3 * exp(-k_3 * t) + c_0_2 * k_2 * {[exp(-k_2 * t) - exp(-k_3 * t)]/[k_3 - k_2]} + c_0_1 * k_1 * k_2 * [1/(k_2-k_1)] * <{[exp(-k_1 * t) - exp(-k_3 * t)]/[k_3 - k_1]} - {[exp(-k_2 * t) - exp(-k_3 * t)]/[k_3 - k_2]}>
```

As you can see, each equation is a sum of reappearing elements. The number of nestings is dependent on the degree of relationship: 0-th degree (A to A) - simple exponential function, 1st degree (A to B, B to C, etc.) - 1 nesting, 2nd degree (A to C, B to D, etc.) - 2 nestings, etc.

Each equation can be divided into reappearing parts:

- the 'independent' unit: c_0_n * exp(-k_n * t),
- the basic unit: f(a,b) = (exp(- k_n[b - 1] * t) - exp(- k_n[a - 1] * t)) / (k_n[a - 1] - k_n[b - 1]),
- the nested unit based on the basic unit,
- the product of the multiplication of constants (parameters) before each nested unit.

Each nested unit of the nth equation derives from the nested units of the (n-1)th equation. The equations themselves can be obtained through iterated integration. The number of possible equations (based on the number of independent kinetic constants k) for the nth reagent is given by Bell number B(n).

Each such equation can be obtained from the equation with n independent kinetic constants for the nth reagent (all are independent of one another). One simply has to find the limes of such equation. E.g. if k_3 = k_4 and k_7 = k_2, then we are looking for lim k_4->k_3 [lim k_7->k_2 (f(t))].

The working code:

```
print
print ("Commands: komendy() - list of commands, test() - sets initial parameters, zakres() - asks for the number of reagents, tabela() - displays the table, stez() - asks for the initial concentrations, kin() - asks for the kinetic constants.")
print

n = 0

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

def komendy(): # displays the list of commands
    print
    print ("Commands: komendy() - list of commands, test() - sets initial parameters, zakres() - asks for the number of reagents, tabela() - displays the table, stez() - asks for the initial concentrations, kin() - asks for the kinetic constants.")
    print
    return

def zakres(): # number of reagents query
    global n, zakres_n, c_0_n, k_n
    n = int(raw_input("Define the number of n reagents: "))
    zakres_n = range(1, n + 1)
    c_0_n = [int(0)] * n
    k_n = [int(0)] * n
    return

def stez(): # initial concentrations query
    while True:
        y = int(raw_input("Define the value of c_0_n for n equal to (press 0 to break): "))
        if y == 0:
            break
        x = raw_input("Define the value of c_0_" + str(y) + ": ")
        if "." in x:
            c_0_n[y - 1] = float(x)
        else:
            c_0_n[y - 1] = int(x)
    return

def kin(): # kinetic constants query
    while True:
        q = int(raw_input("Define the value of k_n for n equal to (press 0 to break): "))
        if q == 0:
            break
        p = raw_input("Define the value of k_" + str(q) + ": ")
        if "." in p:
            k_n[q - 1] = float(p)
        else:
            k_n[q - 1] = int(p)
    return

def tabela(): # displays the table with the initial data
    if n == 0:
        zakres()
        print
        print "n:     ", zakres_n
        print "c_0_n: ", c_0_n
        print "k_n:   ", k_n
        print
    else:
        print
        print "n:     ", zakres_n
        print "c_0_n: ", c_0_n
        print "k_n:   ", k_n
        print
    return

def wykres(): # plots the basic unit
    global f_t, t_k, t, t_d
    a = int(raw_input("a = "))
    b = int(raw_input("b = "))
    reag = map(int, raw_input("Provide the reagents to plot (separate with spacebar): ").split(" "))
    t_k = float(raw_input("Define time range from 0 to: "))
    t_d = float(raw_input("Set the precision of the time axis: "))
    t = np.arange(0,t_k,t_d)
    p = []
    def f_t(t):
        return (np.exp(- k_n[b - 1] * t) - np.exp(- k_n[a - 1] * t)) / (k_n[a - 1] - k_n[b - 1])
    f_t = f_t(t)
    for i in reag:
        p += plt.plot(t,i*f_t)
```

And the code that doesn't work [yet] (the only difference is the new wykres() function I'm trying to build):

```
print
print ("Commands: komendy() - list of commands, test() - sets initial parameters, zakres() - asks for the number of reagents, tabela() - displays the table, stez() - asks for the initial concentrations, kin() - asks for the kinetic constants.")
print

n = 0

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

def komendy(): # displays the list of commands
    print
    print ("Commands: komendy() - list of commands, test() - sets initial parameters, zakres() - asks for the number of reagents, tabela() - displays the table, stez() - asks for the initial concentrations, kin() - asks for the kinetic constants.")
    print
    return

def zakres(): # number of reagents query
    global n, zakres_n, c_0_n, k_n
    n = int(raw_input("Define the number of n reagents: "))
    zakres_n = range(1, n + 1)
    c_0_n = [int(0)] * n
    k_n = [int(0)] * n
    return

def stez(): # initial concentrations query
    while True:
        y = int(raw_input("Define the value of c_0_n for n equal to (press 0 to break): "))
        if y == 0:
            break
        x = raw_input("Define the value of c_0_" + str(y) + ": ")
        if "." in x:
            c_0_n[y - 1] = float(x)
        else:
            c_0_n[y - 1] = int(x)
    return

def kin(): # kinetic constants query
    while True:
        q = int(raw_input("Define the value of k_n for n equal to (press 0 to break): "))
        if q == 0:
            break
        p = raw_input("Define the value of k_" + str(q) + ": ")
        if "." in p:
            k_n[q - 1] = float(p)
        else:
            k_n[q - 1] = int(p)
    return

def tabela(): # displays the table with the initial data
    if n == 0:
        zakres()
        print
        print "n:     ", zakres_n
        print "c_0_n: ", c_0_n
        print "k_n:   ", k_n
        print
    else:
        print
        print "n:     ", zakres_n
        print "c_0_n: ", c_0_n
        print "k_n:   ", k_n
        print
    return

def wykres(): # plots the requested functions
    global t_k, t, t_d, f, constans
    reag = map(int, raw_input("Provide the reagents to plot (separate with spacebar): ").split(" "))
    t_k = float(raw_input("Define the time range from 0 to: "))
    t_d = float(raw_input("Define the precision of the time axis: "))
    t = np.arange(0,t_k,t_d)
    p = []

    def f(a,b): # basic unit
        return  (np.exp(- k_n[b - 1] * t) - np.exp(- k_n[a - 1] * t)) / (k_n[a - 1] - k_n[b - 1])

    def const(l,r): # products appearing before the nested parts
        const = 1
        constans = 1
        for h in range(l,r):
            const = const * k_n[h]
        constans = c_0_n[l] * const
        return

    def czlonF(g): # nested part
        czlonF = 0
        for u in range(g):
            czlonF = czlonF + npoch(f(a,b),g)

        if g == 1:
            czlonF(g) = 0
        return

    def npoch(f(a,b),n):
        f = f(a,b)
        for x in range(b+1, n+1):
            f = npoch(f(a,b),x)
        return

    def c(j): # final result, concentration in time function
        return

    def czlon0(m): # 'independent' part
        return (c_0_n[m - 1] * np.exp(- k_n[m - 1] * t))

    for i in reag: # the actual plot command
        p += plt.plot(t,c(i))
    plt.show()
    return

def test():
    global n, zakres_n, k_n, c_0_n
    n = 5
    zakres_n = range(1, n + 1)
    k_n = [1,2,3,4,5]
    c_0_n = [2,3,4,5,6]
    return
    plt.show()
    return

def test():
    global n, zakres_n, k_n, c_0_n
    n = 5
    zakres_n = range(1, n + 1)
    k_n = [1,2,3,4,5]
    c_0_n = [2,3,4,5,6]
    return
```

How do I fix the wykres() function so that it plots c(n)? How do I build it so that it can be plotted? I want Python to automatically build c_n(t) for whichever n I desire and plot all of them.

Comment: The question is: how do I fix the wykres() function so that it plots c(n). How do I build it so that it can be plotted.

Comment: I want Python to automatically build c_n(t) for whichever n I desire and plot all of them.